# start android activity within cordova project

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

Is it possible to call the following code within a cordova project?

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.net.vpn.SETTINGS");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

I tried to use WebIntent ([link](https://github.com/darryncampbell/darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent)), but it does not support the set of a flag, furthermore I dont know how I have to set the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer

*No*

#### Detailed answer:

Cordova uses one Activity only (Web View) so you cannot open new Activity.

But Ionic (Angular) supports states and you can switch views inside web view

---

What you try to do is to open Settings that is not part of your application.

So you can call Java method from Cordova and call your code

*Java*

```
private boolean openWifiSettings(final CallbackContext callbackContext) {

        final CordovaPlugin plugin = this;

        this.cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {


                     cordova.startActivityForResult(plugin, new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), 0);

                    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK));

            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

and in javascript:

```
YourPlugin.prototype.openWifiSettings = function (successCallback, errorCallback) {
  cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "MoodoPlugin", "openWifiSettings", []); //
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any example how to call a java method from cordova?

Comment: Where I have do define this code and how can I call it?

Comment: @SaskiaB well, you can find a lot of examples how to call method from javascript. :) I think I answered on your question.

Comment: @SaskiaB you can write your own plugin to communicate with native code by yourself

Comment: Yes, im thinking about the same. I'm gonna try that.